# handle client disconnect with openfire server If the client is idle for 5mins

Tags: python, xmpp, openfire

I wrote a demo about chatting with other clients with pyxmpp2，but when the client is idle for about 5 minutes the server would disconnect with the client,openfire cannot  config  the timeout,so I decide to send a presence message in 5 minutes ,the problem puzzling me is when to  send the prensense message?

```
import pyxmpp2

class EchoBot(EventHandler, XMPPFeatureHandler):
    """Echo Bot implementation."""
    def __init__(self, my_jid, settings):
        version_provider = VersionProvider(settings)
        self.client = Client(my_jid, [self, version_provider], settings)
    @event_handler(AuthorizedEvent)
    def handle_authorized(self,event):
        presence = Presence(to_jid ="....",stanza_type = "available")
        self.client.stream.send(presence)
    def run(self):
        """Request client connection and start the main loop."""
        self.client.connect()
        self.client.run()
    def disconnect(self):
        """"""
        self.client.disconnect()
    def keepconnect(self):
        presence = Presence(to_jid ="....",stanza_type = "available")
        self.client.stream.send(presence)
        print "send presence"
....
bot = McloudBot(JID(mcloudbotJID), settings)
try:
        bot.run()        
        t = threading.Thread(target=bot.run())
        timer=threading.Timer(5,bot.keepconnect())
        t.start()
        timer.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        bot.disconnect()
```

but it seems not work...

Answer (score 0):

Check out

http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2053

This details the dissconnect idle property in OF that you can set to a value in milli seconds

Dissconnecting idle clients is something that's important in session based comms. It has more to do with the client closing unexpectedly rather than just neing idle though.

You can implement ping or heartbeat packet sending in your client as you mention above. Maybe check out the pidgin implementation of whitespace IQ requests.

Hope this steers you in the right direction.

James